# unable to encrypt message in matrix-js-sdk

Tags: vue.js

I'm used 'olm' version '3.1.4' and 'matrix-js-sdk' version '2.4.6'
Trying use end to end encryption supported in matrix using olm

I'm using the following code snipping:

```
    const cryptoStore = new sdk.MemoryCryptoStore(window.localStorage);
         const webStorageSessionStore = new sdk.WebStorageSessionStore(window.localStorage);
         var matrixStore = new sdk.MatrixInMemoryStore();

         matrixClient = sdk.createClient({
           baseUrl: 'SERVER_HOME',
           accessToken: token,
           userId: 'USER_ID',
           store: matrixStore,
           sessionStore: webStorageSessionStore,
           cryptoStore: cryptoStore,
           deviceId: 'DEVICE_ID'});

matrixClient.initCrypto()
       .then(() => {
         matrixClient.startClient({ initialSyncLimit: 10 });
       })
```

1- I have error with post key/upload API bad request

```
REQUEST: POST Request URL: https://SERVER_HOME/_matrix/client/r0/keys/upload/DEVICE_ID?access_token=XXXX

RESPONSE: 400 Bad Request {"errcode":"M_UNKNOWN","error":"One time key signed_curve25519:XXXX already exists. Old key: {\"key\":\"64zJVMH61Toei8Kaz2SRXEZ4VyNBjjG2vfaGjSXXXX\",\"signatures\":{\"@USER_ID\":{\"ed25519:869254020336060\":\"HBnlhazYGY+IrvImq5d4OcIYsXeo094St2p/SMYWobMfteML1gH1jMSUmAh9o7EYIXQMnshiPSh6FSdL4XXXXw\"}}}; new key: {'key': 'VSfPQ7NFzdPl0owA1pVK8CqTzLCyF6NQCuS8aTIIYmc', 'signatures': {'@USER_ID': {'ed25519:869254020336060': 'rIQHea/3kh5w8PaC91H83zsTKQDevbkPpnJ5Dpj7YHv3o4Jzq1O3AmgMzfhFzhlXBwn1N6gRPfC+jNMCIPXXXX'}}}"}
```

2- When I test it with encryption Roit room and try to send message from sdk to Roit find this is error get this error

```
Error sending event UnknownDeviceError: This room contains unknown devices which have not been verified. We strongly recommend you verify them before continuing.
```

3- When I test it with encryption Roit room and send message from Roit to sdk I get this error

```
Error decrypting event (id=xxxx): DecryptionError[msg: The sender's device has not sent us the keys for this message., session: FoIZTb4W906iFiQofhzgyZlkjeR9XazjN9vfIC9uzFQ|nCwWvT+VU/FVz7uNLojW51+PtkrXj++eMC1d/Xxxxxxx]
```

Comment: Did you solve the `Error sending event UnknownDeviceError:` ?